# Remove similar duplicates from dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

How would I remove rows in a dataframe whose values are within a certain threshold?

```
                x             y
1   -0.111111e-15  0.111111e-15
2   -1.111112e-15  1.111112e-15
3   -1.111111e-15  1.111111e-15
```

For example if I set the threshold to `1e^-8`, the second or third row will be removed.

Comment: Let's say your threshold is .1. If you have .05,.14, and .23, should .05 and .23 be combined?

Comment: Anyway, you might try (using `data.table` notation) `unique(dt[,lapply(.SD,round,8)])`

Comment: @MichaelChirico Good idea, that would work.

Comment: just make sure `dt` is not keyed first, otherwise use `unique(setkeyv(dt,names(dt))[,lapply(.SD,round,8)])` or `unique(dt[,lapply(.SD,round,8)],by=names(dt))`

Comment: @MichaelChirico just `setkey(dt)` will key by all the columns but I doubt OP even has a `data.table` object, not to mention a keyed one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I input console output with a little utility function rd.txt:

```
> dat <- rd.txt("                x             y
+ 1   -0.111111e-15  0.111111e-15
+ 2   -1.111112e-15  1.111112e-15
+ 3   -1.111111e-15  1.111111e-15"
+ )
> dat[ ! duplicated( round(dat,-8) ),]
             x           y
1 -1.11111e-16 1.11111e-16
```

(My first version with a minus sign rather than a negation operator was not correct.) This would need some modifications if all the columns were not numeric. If tht's the case then please post a proper test example, preferably with dput()-output rather than console output which is often ambiguous.

With the example from the other respondent (modified to deliver the requested object class):

```
dfrm<-data.frame(id=letters[1:3],x=c(-1/9/1e15,-1/9/1e14,-1/9/1e14),
               y=c(1/9/1e15,1/9/1e14,1/9/1e14))
dfrm[ ! duplicated( round( dfrm[ , sapply(dfrm, is.numeric)],8)), ]
  id             x            y
1  a -1.111111e-16 1.111111e-16
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible `data.table` (if your data is now a `data.frame` `df`, just set `dt<-data.table(df)`).

A more complicated version of your data, with non numeric columns:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id=letters[1:3],
                 x=c(-1/9/1e15,-1/9/1e14,-1/9/1e14),
                 y=c(1/9/1e15,1/9/1e14,1/9/1e14))
```

Now we just round all the numeric columns to your threshold and find unique rows:

```
indx <- names(dt)[sapply(dt, is.numeric)]  ## Find numeric columns
unique(dt[, lapply(.SD, round, 8), .SDcols = indx])
#    x y
# 1: 0 0
```

Alternatively, you can keep both the numeric *and* non-numeric columns while subsetting only by the *numeric* columns

```
unique(dt[, (indx) := lapply(.SD, round, 8), .SDcols = indx], by = indx)
#    id x y
# 1:  a 0 0
```

Comment: I think you are a bit overcomplicating this. You need to create the index only *once* and you certainly don't need a `by` argument here. Just `indx <- names(dt)[sapply(dt, is.numeric)] ; unique(dt[, lapply(.SD, round, 8), .SDcols = indx])` will do.

Comment: Alternatively, you could keep *all* the columns by simply doing `unique(dt[, (indx) := lapply(.SD, round, 8), .SDcols = indx], by = indx)`

Comment: I've took the libirity to a bit *enhance* your answer if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach using `dplyr` that would work on both `data.table` or `data.frame`

```
dfrm<-data.frame(id=letters[1:3],x=c(-1/9/1e15,-1/9/1e14,-1/9/1e14),
                 y=c(1/9/1e15,1/9/1e14,1/9/1e14))

library(dplyr)
dfrm %>%
  # select only numeric columns
  select(which(sapply(., is.numeric))) %>%
  # remove rows
  slice(which(!duplicated(round(., -8)))) %>%
  # right join the result with original dataset (get back unselected non-numeric columns)
  right_join(dfrm, .)
```